# Microsoft Office Word (2007) - sidebar with document structure

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Is it possible to visualize a sidebar with the document structure in word 2007? Something like this exists for PowerPoint (thumbnails of the slides) and in some PDF reader (thumbnails of the pages or tree view of the headings), but I don't manage to find it in Word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the View tab on the Ribbon and select the Document Map check box in the Show/Hide group.

— [Dummies - How to use the document map in Word 2007?](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-document-map-in-word-2007.html#ixzz1C9jer7Fw)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using Word 2010 - Select the **View** tab on the Ribbon and select the **Navigation Pane** option in the **Show** window.